# Select specifics items from array objects in mongoose

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an mongoDB objetc like :

```
[
  {
    "items": [
      {
        "title": "hello",
        "options": [
          {
            "value": "A",
            "image": "img1",
            "des": "des1"
          },
          {
            "value": "B",
            "image": "img2",
            "des": "des2"
          },
          
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

When I retrieve data from the collection, I want to retrieve only `value` key from the `options` of the `items` array.

Output should look like :

```
{
 "items":[
  {
     "options" :[
       {  "value" :"A" },
       {  "value" :"B" },
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

How can i do this?

Comment: use projection `{ "items.options.value": 1 }` see more about [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projection).

Comment: `turivishal` If you specify the query it would be helpful for me. Thanks

Comment: it is same you can use projection as per my comment, if you want to use aggregation then see [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html)

Comment: if you see the attached links in comment, its easy to use, just follow the instructions as per documentation. it is not hard to understand I think you just have to use `{ "items.options.value": 1 }` projection simple.

Comment: Ok, I am trying

Comment: Working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
db.collection.find({}, { "items.options.value": 1})
```

Here is the working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/FqDaQ7Q-y-Y

Or you can do it like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "items.options.value": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/jPFYtXYBvpI